# Prolog number of items which contain woman

Tags: prolog

How I can find

1. number of circles which contain at least 1 woman?
2. names of people who meet in more circles

```
circle(circle1, [misha, inna]).
circle(circle2, [misha, inna, igor, ivan]).
circle(circle3, [vasya, stepan]).

gender(misha, man).
gender(inna, woman).
gender(igor, man).
gender(ivan, man).
gender(vasya, man).
gender(stepan, man).
```

Answer (score 1):

We can define these predicates:

```
% Member is a woman.
woman(Member) :- gender(Member, woman).

% Circle contains at least Number women.
contains_at_least_women(Circle, Number) :-
    circle(Circle, Members),
    include(woman, Members, Women),
    length(Women, WomanCount),
    WomanCount >= Number.

% There are two circles in which two different women appear 
share_circle(Woman1, Woman2) :-
    circle(Circle1, Members1),
    circle(Circle2, Members2),
    Circle1 \== Circle2,
    member(Woman1, Members1),
    member(Woman2, Members1),
    member(Woman1, Members2),
    member(Woman2, Members2),
    % Enforces that the pair is alphabetically ordered,
    % thus preferring [X,Y] over [Y,X] and removing duplicates.
    Woman1 @< Woman2,
    Woman1 \== Woman2.

% The women who share multiple circles (but not necessarily all with one another)
share_circles(Women) :-
    setof([Woman1, Woman2], share_circle(Woman1, Woman2), Women).
```

With this we can query the following:

```
?- contains_at_least_women(Circle, 1).
Circle = circle1 ;
Circle = circle2 ;

?- share_circles(Women).
Women = [[inna, misha]].
```